# Place Text Beneath CSS Preloader

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put some text centered beneath my CSS preloader that says "Loading Options - This May Take A Few Seconds..."

```css
#loader {
  border: 16px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid rgb(27, 40, 61);
  /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -60px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

#loader:after {
  content: "Loading Options - This May Take A Few Seconds...";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
}
@keyframes spin {
0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div id="search-overlay">
  <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
```

However, this causes the text to spin with the loader, not static below it.  Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: the loader doesn't spin

Comment: Apologies - edited and updated

Comment: Is it a must to use pseudo? Simply put them in two div already solve the problem.

Comment: @user3682157 if my answer helped you please mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a new element :)

Combine that with a more little css to make it look more snazzy.

```css
#loader {
  border: 16px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid rgb(27, 40, 61);
  /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#loader:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
}
@keyframes spin {
0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
#search-overlay {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#loader-text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div id="search-overlay">
  <div id="loader"></div>
  <div id="loader-text">Loading Options:<br> This may take a few seconds...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The text is not yet beneath the loader

Comment: @ToanLu Looks underneath the loader to me just fine ;) Thanks for the catch, I updated it

Comment: @sheshan-s I think I looked at the old code I guess

Comment: Yes maybe @ToanLu

Comment: This works but for some reason, the text appears on the top of the screen as opposed to below the loader.  I assume because of the funky margins I am using...

Comment: You can post that as another question I guess, but if this helped please upvote and mark as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new element for this. There would be no other way. Because you are rotating the complete set of element and that text is the content of the rotator.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve such thing with `flex` display.

The `:after` pseudo still belongs with `#loader`, so you cannot prevent it from spinning while setting animation for `#loader`.

You need to create a new element to handle such message.

In addition, using position `absolute` and negative margin value is not really a best practice. I don't know the context while you must use such combination but I think just using `top` & `left` value seems to be enough.

```css
#loader {
  border: 16px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid rgb(27, 40, 61);
  /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

#search-overlay {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="search-overlay">
  <div id="loader"></div>
  <span class="loading-message">Loading Options - This May Take A Few Seconds...</span>
</div>
```